# C# Visual Studio - I'm trying to read a text file and display it into Richtextbox and include new lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to read a text file and display it into Richtextbox and include new lines.
Say I want it to read as:

Hello

Hello

Hello

But it is reading as:
HelloHelloHello

This is the code that I have so far:

```
private  void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    op.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    op.Filter = "Txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    op.FilterIndex = 2;

    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = op.FileName;
        string path = op.FileName;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while(sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
            }
        }

        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();                
    }
}
```

Comment: Also:viewing the text in a notepad does include the text, so it is writing to the text file correctly, it just is not reading it.

Comment: The `StringBuilder` class has a few options for appending text. The one you're using, `Append()` just appends the text. But there's another one, called `AppendLine()` that also puts a line break at the end. Use that one instead, and get rid of `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StreamReader` lines are delimited by `Environment.NewLine`. If you'd read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you would have noticed `ReadLine` does not include these delimiters. If you want to re-add them use:

```
sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

And don't call `Console.WriteLine()` in a WinForms app.

Comment: Or just do one call to `sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do it is to use the `File` class's static `ReadAllText()` method.

You just pass it the path to a text file, and it will read all the text (line breaks included) into a string and return it to you. Then you can just set the result of that to your `richTextBox1.Text` property for some much cleaner and easier to read code:

```
if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = op.FileName;
    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(op.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line:

```
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
```

to:

```
sb.Append("/r/n");
```